# Messages is unusable due to unresponsiveness!

Tags: messages, performance, bug

Messages on High Sierra has become increasingly unusable for me. I get frequent (every dozen words or so, at least once per message) long (5-20s) lags when typing — which seem to occur most often when something ambiguous has been entered (a typo or incomplete word) — or when switching to the Messages window.

Messages has been increased slow and a resource hog on macOS (to the point where I just shut it off most of the time) in general, but this unresponsiveness is the major annoyance.

What causes this and how can I fix it?

---

I've followed suggestions I've found online to turn off syncing of contacts in all accounts but one (in my case iCloud), but that seems to have no effect.

---

Pauses *seem to be* associated with log entries (filtered on "contact" errors) like the following, but it could be many other things too (e.g., changes of focus to Messages), and there's no clear association with the exact logging of an error and the lag:

```
default 11:47:26.437362 -0500   fmfd    There was an error while trying to load accounts. We'll return an empty array. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated.}
error   11:47:26.481193 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   11:47:26.610413 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   11:47:26.733041 -0500   AppleSpell  Contacts change history truncated, resetting!
default 11:47:31.437365 -0500   fmfd    There was an error while trying to load accounts. We'll return an empty array. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated.}
error   11:47:37.781508 -0500   AppleSpell  Contacts change history truncated, resetting!
error   11:48:27.269667 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   11:48:27.387438 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   11:48:27.593285 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
default 11:48:27.783845 -0500   fmfd    There was an error while trying to load accounts. We'll return an empty array. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated.}
error   11:48:27.794354 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   11:48:28.294191 -0500   AppleSpell  Contacts change history truncated, resetting!
default 11:48:33.094905 -0500   fmfd    There was an error while trying to load accounts. We'll return an empty array. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated.}
error   11:48:44.490877 -0500   AppleSpell  Contacts change history truncated, resetting!
```

---

[A related question focused on a possible cause](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/312393/4395) (perhaps extending beyond Messages).

Comment: Could you open Console.app and then replicate the issue in messages? It would help to see the console log.

Comment: @Ckacmaster What log should I look for?

Comment: @Ckacmaster Added some log output.

Comment: Completely different reason, same answer. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/310872/85275

Comment: Have you actually _deleted_ ALL the accounts from `System Preferences > Internet  Accounts`, not merely stopped the syncing thereof?

Comment: @IconDaemon: Is that necessary. It might be easier to abandon Apple for another OS.

Comment: That's your choice. It's easy to add them all back if you want to, especially if it solves the problem.

Comment: @IconDaemon: I was hoping for narrowing down the issue a bit before conceding that this was necessary.

Comment: Sometimes breaking it all down and starting fresh clears out cruft.

Comment: @IconDaemon: Yes but since users are no longer Apple's focus, there's not much keeping me here once I break it all down.

Comment: It looks like Apple may have fixed this in Mojave.