# AppleSpell error: Contacts change history truncated, resetting!

Tags: contacts, performance, error, bug, spellcheck

My macOS High Sierra system is increasingly slowing to a crawl and having huge spikes in CPU usage, [notably in Messages](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/310818/4395), but even when it not running.

The logs that seem to be most closely associated with the errors I'm getting are listed below (filtered for "contacts" and "errors" in the Console app). But that's as far as I've gotten after hours of sleuthing.

FWIW: Though I have many "internet accounts" enabled (and more disabled), I only use contacts from iCloud. No other accounts are used for contacts.

What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

---

Note that I also had what appears to be related errors of the form

```
localhost AppleSpell[46481]: (CoreData) [com.apple.coredata:error] error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///var/db/CoreDuet/People//interactionC.db options:{
    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 0;
    NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 0;
    NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption = 1;
} ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." with userInfo dictionary {
}
```

which I simply eliminated with

```
sudo chmod o+r /private/var/db/CoreDuet/PeopleinteractionC.*
```

(which I assume is safe?); but that seems to have had no effect.

---

Key errors that seem to be involved in triggering the error cascade and CPU ramp up are (in no order):

```
error   10:33:34.557880 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"

error   10:33:39.558575 -0500   mds ====^^^^ QUERY CLIENT _showAllExtensions:0

error   10:33:34.607541 -0500   accountsd   "Cannot check access to a private account type: com.apple.account.AppleAccount"

error   10:34:00.567089 -0500   Mail    [AOSAccounts] : [ACAccount+iCloudAccount] : -[ACAccount(iCloudAccount) icaCloudKitToken] - icaCloudKitToken cannot be returned as account is still not vetted!

error   10:33:50.189500 -0500   Messages    error:  API Misuse: Attempt to serialize store access on non-owning coordinator (PSC = 0x600002c79c80, store PSC = 0x0)
```

---

In addition I get occasional crashes of AppleSpell:

```
Process:               AppleSpell [46000]
Path:                  /System/Library/Services/AppleSpell.service/Contents/MacOS/AppleSpell
Identifier:            AppleSpell
Version:               2.4 (430.1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           AppleSpell [46000]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2018-01-20 10:42:36.335 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.2 (17C205)
Report Version:        12

Time Awake Since Boot: 210000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       6700 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        4  Dispatch queue: com.apple.eventkit.eventstore.backingobjects

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000007fca4a08190
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0x7fca4a08190:
    SQLite page cache      00000001196c4000-0000000119744000 [  512K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--> 
    STACK GUARD            000070000c046000-000070000c047000 [    4K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  stack guard for thread 1

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: respondsToSelector:


Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6da977c2 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6da96cdc mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4604f355 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4604e6a7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4604dd23 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4608c773 CFRunLoopRun + 99
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff4830aadd -[NSSpellServer run] + 73
7   com.apple.AppleSpell            0x0000000105388b98 0x105387000 + 7064
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6d951114 0x7fff6d950000 + 4372
```

---

Example log, filtered for "contacts" and "errors" in the Console app:

```
error   15:22:55.776668 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   15:22:56.223723 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   15:22:56.308076 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
default 15:23:00.803149 -0500   fmfd    There was an error while trying to load accounts. We'll return an empty array. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated.}
error   15:23:05.890741 -0500   AppleSpell  Contacts change history truncated, resetting!
error   15:23:27.441065 -0500   AppleSpell  Contacts change history truncated, resetting!
error   15:23:51.628696 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   15:23:51.750564 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
default 15:23:51.757146 -0500   fmfd    There was an error while trying to load accounts. We'll return an empty array. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated.}
error   15:23:54.968141 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   15:23:55.094349 -0500   AppleSpell  Contacts change history truncated, resetting!
default 15:23:56.761515 -0500   fmfd    There was an error while trying to load accounts. We'll return an empty array. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated.}
error   15:24:24.784348 -0500   AppleSpell  Contacts change history truncated, resetting!
error   15:24:52.004381 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   15:24:52.153096 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
default 15:24:53.276190 -0500   fmfd    There was an error while trying to load accounts. We'll return an empty array. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated.}
error   15:24:53.275323 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   15:24:54.345358 -0500   AppleSpell  Contacts change history truncated, resetting!
default 15:24:57.343831 -0500   fmfd    There was an error while trying to load accounts. We'll return an empty array. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated.}
error   15:25:09.740347 -0500   AppleSpell  Contacts change history truncated, resetting!
error   15:25:52.345986 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   15:25:52.435518 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   15:25:52.602685 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
default 15:25:52.651438 -0500   fmfd    There was an error while trying to load accounts. We'll return an empty array. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated.}
error   15:25:52.793656 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   15:25:53.195679 -0500   AppleSpell  Contacts change history truncated, resetting!
default 15:25:58.789192 -0500   fmfd    There was an error while trying to load accounts. We'll return an empty array. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated.}
error   15:26:11.595438 -0500   AppleSpell  Contacts change history truncated, resetting!
error   15:26:51.177684 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   15:26:51.262879 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   15:26:51.561885 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
default 15:26:51.554447 -0500   fmfd    There was an error while trying to load accounts. We'll return an empty array. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated.}
error   15:26:51.675959 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   15:26:51.848946 -0500   AppleSpell  Contacts change history truncated, resetting!
default 15:26:57.096821 -0500   fmfd    There was an error while trying to load accounts. We'll return an empty array. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated.}
error   15:27:08.544743 -0500   AppleSpell  Contacts change history truncated, resetting!
error   15:27:53.683675 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   15:27:53.760238 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   15:27:54.064740 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
default 15:27:54.223637 -0500   fmfd    There was an error while trying to load accounts. We'll return an empty array. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated.}
error   15:27:54.232621 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   15:27:54.592746 -0500   AppleSpell  Contacts change history truncated, resetting!
default 15:28:00.756454 -0500   fmfd    There was an error while trying to load accounts. We'll return an empty array. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated.}
error   15:28:17.250338 -0500   AppleSpell  Contacts change history truncated, resetting!
error   15:28:51.156290 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   15:28:51.265767 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   15:28:51.719235 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
default 15:28:51.729694 -0500   fmfd    There was an error while trying to load accounts. We'll return an empty array. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated.}
error   15:28:52.456345 -0500   AppleSpell  Contacts change history truncated, resetting!
default 15:28:57.013217 -0500   fmfd    There was an error while trying to load accounts. We'll return an empty array. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated.}
error   15:29:11.709886 -0500   AppleSpell  Contacts change history truncated, resetting!
error   15:29:52.724254 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   15:29:52.875071 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
default 15:29:53.376194 -0500   fmfd    There was an error while trying to load accounts. We'll return an empty array. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService was invalidated.}
error   15:29:53.402651 -0500   accountsd   Could not donate contact information: Error Domain=CNDonationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error   15:29:53.451609 -0500   AppleSpell  Contacts change history truncated, resetting!
```